# How to show a Random String from Shared Preferences?

Tags: java, string, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I am trying to show a random string with a button click, from a `RecyclerView` list by shared preferences. But if I use the code below, I will get everything in my text field not only the text I want.

It shows me this:

```
[{"mImageResource":0,"mLine1":"i want only this part":""}]
```

Code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final String randomtext = sharedPreferences.getString("task list", "defaultValue");

PushTheButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn1.startAnimation(anim1);
        StartText2.setText(randomtext);
    }
}
```

Code from my `RecyclerView`:

```
private void saveData(){
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(mExampleList);
   editor.putString("task list", json);
   editor.apply();
}

private void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ExampleItem>>(){}.getType();
    mExampleList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    if (mExampleList == null) {
        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you saved in the preferences with "task list" key?

Comment: I am still not so familiar with the whole recyclerview thing. I have one textline, one imagebutton for delete the line.

Comment: You can use the `Random` class of java to choose a number between 1 and n, where n is the total number of items in the list. After which, you can parse the `mLine1` property from your JSON using `Gson` library.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I am totally lost right now. How do i parse a property from JSON?